# Dealing with one-to-many in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, domain-model

Given the below simplified domain model:

**Train Journey**

- id uuid
- train name string (unique within one day)
- date of journey date
- ...

**Journey Stations**

- station uuid
- arrival timestamp
- departure timestamp
- ...

With this relation:

- 1 Train Journey has n Journey Stations

With this query requirements:

- All Train Journeys at a given Station, **including all Journey Stations**, departing between a given timeframe.

How should this query be modelled in Cassandra?

I was thinking about something like:

```
CREATE TABLE departures_by_station (
    date_of_yourney date,
    train_name varchar,
    station uuid,
    arrival timestamp,
    departure timestamp,
    primary key((date_of_journey, station), train_name, departure)
);

SELECT * from departures_by_station 
WHERE date_of_journey = '2018-01-02' AND station = 'Paris' AND departure ...;
```

This will not work because it results in a partial Train Journey - all Journey Stations except the requested one are missing. 
To make it even worse, arrival & departure times may change frequently. I can't update this table with a new departure time because it is a clustering key.

Any idea or hint how to solve this problem? I guess I'm missing something basic here, but I am very new to the nosql world.

Comment: What do you do with historical data - do you keep the "old journeys" or not? And how many journeys do you have per day?

Comment: A couple of tousands a day. Past journeys are ignorable, they will be tracked separate. Lets say we are talking about 7 days of data with 3000 journeys each day.

Comment: And how many stations?

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your time and interest, Alex! I'm talking about 2-100 stations per journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it maybe not the most optimal solution (need to do some calculations about partition size, etc.). If you can expire "old" data using TTL, then I thought about having something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE departures_by_station (
   station uuid,
   departure timestamp,
   train_name varchar,
   arrival timestamp,
   statitions list<uuid>
   primary key(station, departure, train_name)
);
```

In this case you'll have so-called "wide" partitions - one per station of journey, and because you have departure as clustering key, you can do a range search on it. But if you expire quite a lot of data, then you need to perform "repairing" of tables quite often to get rid of tombstones (deletions markers) because this could affect read performance.

Also, to avoid doing multiple lookups, you need to put information about all stations along journey into every row - I wrote this as `list<uuid>`, but it could be better modeled as user-defined type, so you can include station name, and other information.

You code also should generate an entry for every station along journey for particular train.

P.S. I recommend to take a DS220 (Data Modeling) course on [DataStax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com/).

Comment: TTL expiry is not possible but I could handle old data on every read and delete it. I will try to adapt your solution and do the partition size calculation.

Comment: It's not necessary to handle it on every read as if you search by range, then these data won't be visible. You can setup periodic batch  clean-up of data via cron, for example

Comment: It's not that easy, mainly because the above domain model is hugely simplified. For example, there are multiple departure times (planned, estimated, verified, ...) and these times get updated which would result in inserts. The range search would still include the old data. I need to think about this a bit more, I'm already scared of the potential amount of data.

Comment: But do you really need Cassandra for that amount of data?

Comment: Good question :) I'm still evaluating if Cassandra is a good option for this task. The current relational approach (Oracle)  has reached it's limits for this sort of queries (joins all over).

Comment: 10 years ago I did a lot of improvements in performance of Oracle by denormalizing some tables - same as Cassandra does